# Drop Down Menu Issue (position)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, position, css-position

I need help with the drop down menus. I encounter this issue when I hover on top of the tabs with hidden drop down menus. I followed the W3Schools instructions

The W3Schools instructions asked me to use `position: absolute` but if I do that instead of `position: relative` the drop down menus won't even open.

[image]

```css
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .projects {
  color: #fff39e;
  border: none;
  background-color: #f9fae8;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif, Helvetica;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-projects {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  color: #f9fae8;
  background-color: #101119;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-projects a {
  float: none;
  color: #f9fae8;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif, Helvetica;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 0.6;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-projects a:hover {
  color: #fff39e !important;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-projects {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown .dilettante {
  color: #caf5ce;
  border: none;
  background-color: #f9fae8;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif, Helvetica;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-dilettante {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  color: #f9fae8;
  background-color: #101119;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-dilettante a {
  float: none;
  color: #f9fae8;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif, Helvetica;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 0.6;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-dilettante a:hover {
  color: #caf5ce !important;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-dilettante {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="projects">PROJECTS</button>
  <div class="dropdown-projects">
    <a href="projects/artdirection.html">ART DIRECTION</a>
    <a href="projects/branding.html">BRANDING</a>
    <a href="projects/graphicdesigns.html">GRAPHIC DESIGNS</a>
    <a href="projects/photography.html">PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
  </div>

  <button class="dilettante">DILETTANTE</button>
  <div class="dropdown-dilettante">
    <a href="instagram.html">INSTAGRAM</a>
    <a href="quotes.html">QUOTES</a>
    <a href="playlist.html">PLAYLIST</a>
    <a href="goodreads.html">GOODREADS</a>
    <a href="films.html">FILMS</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I clicked the `<>` and made you a snippet

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML, wrap both menu items in `<div class="dropdown">`.

In the CSS, add `position: absolute` on hover.

```css
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .projects {
  color: #fff39e;
  border: none;
  background-color: #f9fae8;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif, Helvetica;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-projects {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  color: #f9fae8;
  background-color: #101119;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-projects a {
  float: none;
  color: #f9fae8;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif, Helvetica;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 0.6;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-projects a:hover {
  color: #fff39e !important;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-projects {
  display: block;
  /* added */
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown .dilettante {
  color: #caf5ce;
  border: none;
  background-color: #f9fae8;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif, Helvetica;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-dilettante {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  color: #f9fae8;
  background-color: #101119;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-dilettante a {
  float: none;
  color: #f9fae8;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif, Helvetica;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 0.6;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-dilettante a:hover {
  color: #caf5ce !important;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-dilettante {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="projects">PROJECTS</button>
  <div class="dropdown-projects">
    <a href="projects/artdirection.html">ART DIRECTION</a>
    <a href="projects/branding.html">BRANDING</a>
    <a href="projects/graphicdesigns.html">GRAPHIC DESIGNS</a>
    <a href="projects/photography.html">PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dilettante">DILETTANTE</button>
  <div class="dropdown-dilettante">
    <a href="instagram.html">INSTAGRAM</a>
    <a href="quotes.html">QUOTES</a>
    <a href="playlist.html">PLAYLIST</a>
    <a href="goodreads.html">GOODREADS</a>
    <a href="films.html">FILMS</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

use `absolute position` in you dropdown and following code for display

```
.projects:hover + div.dropdown-projects {
   display: block;
}

.dilettante:hover + div.dropdown-dilettante {
   display: block;
}
```

here is the [working file](https://jsfiddle.net/v6vqzw78/1/)

also your code need lots of other improvement.

Comment: If you click the `<>` or "copy snippet to answer"  you can post the code here instead of externally

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for your information but I have start working on code before your editing.

Comment: So copy it in. It only takes a minute

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7h31vgnr/)

You'll have to edit CSS accordingly

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  /* Chnage the Background */
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif, Helvetica;
  line-height: 0.6;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #FFF39E;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

#dilettante {
  color: #E1F7DB !important;
}

#projects {
  color: #FFF39E;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF39E;
}

#dilettantedropdown a:hover {
  color: #CAF5CE;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" id="projects">PROJECTS</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="projects/artdirection.html">ART DIRECTION</a>
      <a href="projects/branding.html">BRANDING</a>
      <a href="projects/graphicdesigns.html">GRAPHIC DESIGNS</a>
      <a href="projects/photography.html">PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn " id="dilettante">DILETTANTE
        </button>
    <div id="dilettantedropdown" class="dropdown-content dilettante">
      <a href="instagram.html">INSTAGRAM</a>
      <a href="quotes.html">QUOTES</a>
      <a href="playlist.html">PLAYLIST</a>
      <a href="goodreads.html">GOODREADS</a>
      <a href="films.html">FILMS</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you click the `<>` button in the editor or click "copy snippet to answer" before editing, you can create a [mcve] here instead of externally. Also please tell us what you added/changed